# Forming Object Using Filter and Map method

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a object which contains information of sources:

multiplierInformation = [
{
groupName: 'RAW MATERIALS',
sourceType : [
{
name: 'Cement',
quantityDescription: '',
quantityFlag: false
}
]
}
]

I need to filter out values based on name property.

Please suggest.

Comment: What is the required output?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? And what's the actual problem with it? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically this should work:

```js
let arrayComingFromBackend = [{
  controls: [],
  count: 1,
  description: "",
  id: null,
  key: "cement",
  name: "Cement",
  quantity: 1,
  sourceFormulaId: "31de1317-f5a5-4620-a854-fcfed851ac78",
  sourceSpecifications: [],
  sourceType: "RAW MATERIALS",
  usageParameters: [],
  length: 1
}];

let multiplierInformation = [{
    groupName: 'RAW MATERIALS',
    sourceType: [{
      name: 'Cement',
      quantityDescription: '',
      quantityFlag: false
    }]
  },
  {
    groupName: 'AIR TRANSPORT',
    sourceType: [{
        name: 'Helicopter',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of Flights',
        quantityFlag: true
      },
      {
        name: 'Air Freight',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of Flights',
        quantityFlag: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    groupName: 'OTHER EQUIPMENT',
    sourceType: [{
        name: 'Non-Road Vehicle',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of this Equipment',
        quantityFlag: true
      },
      {
        name: 'Forklift - Diesel',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of Forklifts',
        quantityFlag: true
      },
      {
        name: 'Crane - Diesel',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of Cranes',
        quantityFlag: true
      },
      {
        name: 'Stationary Equipment',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of this Equipment',
        quantityFlag: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    groupName: 'FACILITY/BUILDING',
    sourceType: [{
        name: 'Office',
        quantityDescription: '',
        quantityFlag: false
      },
      {
        name: 'Warehouse and Storage',
        quantityDescription: '',
        quantityFlag: false
      },
      {
        name: 'Other',
        quantityDescription: '',
        quantityFlag: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    groupName: 'FRAC EQUIPMENT',
    sourceType: [{
        name: 'Tier 2',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of Engines',
        quantityFlag: true
      },
      {
        name: 'Dual Fuel T2',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of Engines',
        quantityFlag: true
      },
      {
        name: 'Tier 4F',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of Engines',
        quantityFlag: true
      },
      {
        name: 'Gas Turbine (based on DLE) 940 BTU Gas',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of Engines',
        quantityFlag: true
      },
      {
        name: 'Gas Turbine (based on WLE) 940 BTU Gas',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of Engines',
        quantityFlag: true
      },
      {
        name: 'Gas Turbine (based on GE SAC) 940 BTU Gas',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of Engines',
        quantityFlag: true
      },
      {
        name: 'Grid Power (Using TX Ercot Grid Emissions)',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of Engines',
        quantityFlag: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    groupName: 'CEMENT EQUIPMENT',
    sourceType: [{
        name: 'Elite Tier 3',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of Units',
        quantityFlag: true
      },
      {
        name: 'Elite Tier 4i',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of Units',
        quantityFlag: true
      },
      {
        name: 'Elite Rebuild',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of Units',
        quantityFlag: true
      },
      {
        name: 'Red Tiger',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of Units',
        quantityFlag: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    groupName: 'RAIL TRANSPORT',
    sourceType: [{
      name: 'Rail Transport',
      quantityDescription: 'Number of Trips',
      quantityFlag: true
    }]
  },
  {
    groupName: 'RIGS',
    sourceType: [{
        name: 'Halliburton Controlled Rig',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of Trips',
        quantityFlag: false
      },
      {
        name: '3rd Party Controlled / Rig Power',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of Trips',
        quantityFlag: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    groupName: 'ROAD TRANSPORT',
    sourceType: [{
        name: 'Passenger Car',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of Vehicles',
        quantityFlag: true
      },
      {
        name: 'Light Duty Vehicle',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of Vehicles',
        quantityFlag: true
      },
      {
        name: 'Medium Duty Vehicle',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of Vehicles',
        quantityFlag: true
      },
      {
        name: 'Heavy Duty Vehicle',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of Vehicles',
        quantityFlag: true
      },
      {
        name: 'Bus',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of Vehicles',
        quantityFlag: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    groupName: 'SEA TRANSPORT',
    sourceType: [{
        name: 'Halliburton Controlled Vessel',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of Vessels',
        quantityFlag: true
      },
      {
        name: '3rd Party Controlled Vessel',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of Vessels',
        quantityFlag: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    groupName: 'WASTE',
    sourceType: [{
        name: 'Waste Disposal',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of Vessels',
        quantityFlag: false
      },
      {
        name: 'Oil Contaminated Waste',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of Vessels',
        quantityFlag: false
      },
      {
        name: 'Lithium Battery',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of Vessels',
        quantityFlag: false
      },
      {
        name: 'Waste Recycling',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of Vessels',
        quantityFlag: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    groupName: 'PS EQUIPMENT',
    sourceType: [{
        name: 'PS Stationary Equipment',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of this Equipment',
        quantityFlag: false
      },
      {
        name: 'PS Self-Driving Equipment',
        quantityDescription: 'Number of this Equipment',
        quantityFlag: false
      }
    ]
  }
]



let res = multiplierInformation.filter(information => {
  for (const item of information.sourceType) {
    return arrayComingFromBackend.every(f => {
      const [key, value] = Object.entries(f)[0];
      return item[key] == value
    });
  }
});
```

```
let arrayComingFromBackend = [{
    controls: [],
    count: 1,
    description: "",
    id: null,
    key: "cement",
    name: "Cement",
    quantity: 1,
    sourceFormulaId: "31de1317-f5a5-4620-a854-fcfed851ac78",
    sourceSpecifications: [],
    sourceType: "RAW MATERIALS",
    usageParameters: [],
    length: 1
}];

let res = multiplierInformation.filter(information => {
    for (const item of information.sourceType) {
        return arrayComingFromBackend.every(f => {
            const [key, value] = Object.entries(f)[0];
            return item[key] == value
        });
    }
});

  
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
/* Printing the name of students who play
basketball using filter and map method
simultaneously. */

// Taking an array of Student object
let students = [
    { id: "001", name: "Anish", sports: "Cricket" },
    { id: "002", name: "Smriti", sports: "Basketball" },
    { id: "003", name: "Rahul", sports: "Cricket" },
    { id: "004", name: "Bakul", sports: "Basketball" },
    { id: "005", name: "Nikita", sports: "Hockey" }
]

/* Applying filter function on students array to
retrieve those students Objects who play
basketball and then the new array returned by
filter method is mapped in order to get the name
of basketball players instead of whole object.*/
let basketballPlayers = students.filter(function (student) {
    return student.sports === "Basketball";
}).map(function (student) {
    return student.name;
})

console.log("Basketball Players are:");

// Printing out the name of Basketball players
basketballPlayers.forEach(function (players) {
    console.log(players);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).